# C# get a textfile from EACH folder,

Tags: c#, directory, file-access

I have a folder structure similar to this:

> HostnameA->DateTimeA->hashdumpDateTimeA.txt
>
> HostnameA->DateTimeB->hashdumpDateTimeB.txt
>
> HostnameA->DateTimeC->hashdumpDateTimeC.txt
>
> HostnameA->DateTimeD->hashdumpDateTimeD.txt

My Goal:
Given a folder(in this case HostnameA) i need to:

1) Get each `hashdumpDateTime.txt` filename and place it in a String array -Assumed the file always exist in all folder-

2) Generate `DropDownBox` using the array (I can figure this out)

3) When user selects a filename via dropdownbox, it will fill my datagridview with the 
contents (I can figure this out)

So my problem really is the #1 since i don't know how to make a loop to check the filename coming from a HostnameA folder, I need to know this since the DateTime of these filenames changes

I really appreciate the future help, thanks and cheers =)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("directoryPath","*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

That will give you all file names.If you don't want just names for example if you want file's full path, and some other attributes (like CreationTime, LastAccessTime) use [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("path");
var files = di.GetFiles("*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

That will return an array of `FileInfo` instances.Then use a loop and do what you want with the files.

Comment: THANKS A LOT! Here is my sample code for those who want to try, just edit it in notepad ~~~~~~~

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\HostnameA\");
      
            foreach (var fi in di.GetFiles("Hashdump*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(fi.DirectoryName);
                Console.WriteLine(fi.Directory);
                Console.WriteLine(fi.CreationTime);
            
            }

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't need to know the exact name of `DirectoryName` or `FileName`, using a `for` loop and a `searchPattern` instead.

```
private string[] GetFileNames(string folder)
{
    var files = new List<string>();
    foreach (var dateTimeFolder in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
    {
        files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(dateTimeFolder, "hashdump*.txt"));
    }
    return files.ToArray();
}
```